# When I run flutter app shows Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.co

Tags: flutter

this pop ups when I run flutter app, I already installed all version of build tool of 30

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted platforms in android sdk and reinstall and it works fine now!